# Extracting a dictionary from a multilevel array using indexPath.row

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm having difficulty extracting a dictionary from a multilevel array which is declared as:

`NSArray *menuItems;` and looks like this:

```
Table =     (
                {
            MENUDESC = "HOME           ";
            MENUID = 1072;
            NAVIGATETO = "content.aspx?item=1072&pid=0";
            NAVIGATETO2 = "default.aspx?item=1072&pid=0";
            PARENTMENUID = "<null>";
            PROTECTED = "<null>";
            parentmenuid2 = "<null>";
        },
                {
            MENUDESC = "PRODUCTS &amp; SERVICES";
            MENUID = 1073;
            NAVIGATETO = "#";
            NAVIGATETO2 = "default.aspx?item=1073&pid=0";
            PARENTMENUID = "<null>";
            PROTECTED = "<null>";
            parentmenuid2 = "<null>";
        },
                {
            MENUDESC = "ABOUT US";
            MENUID = 1074;
            NAVIGATETO = "content.aspx?item=1074&pid=0";
            NAVIGATETO2 = "default.aspx?item=1074&pid=0";
            PARENTMENUID = "<null>";
            PROTECTED = "<null>";
            parentmenuid2 = "<null>";
        },
                {
            MENUDESC = "WHAT SETS US APART";
            MENUID = 1075;
            NAVIGATETO = "content.aspx?item=1075&pid=0";
            NAVIGATETO2 = "default.aspx?item=1075&pid=0";
            PARENTMENUID = "<null>";
            PROTECTED = "<null>";
            parentmenuid2 = "<null>";
        },
                {
            MENUDESC = "CASE STUDIES";
            MENUID = 1126;
            NAVIGATETO = "content.aspx?item=1126&pid=0";
            NAVIGATETO2 = "default.aspx?item=1126&pid=0";
            PARENTMENUID = "<null>";
            PROTECTED = "<null>";
            parentmenuid2 = "<null>";
        },
                {
            MENUDESC = "REQUEST PROPOSAL";
            MENUID = 1076;
            NAVIGATETO = "content.aspx?item=1076&pid=0";
            NAVIGATETO2 = "default.aspx?item=1076&pid=0";
            PARENTMENUID = "<null>";
            PROTECTED = "<null>";
            parentmenuid2 = "<null>";
        },
                {
            MENUDESC = CONTACT;
            MENUID = 1077;
            NAVIGATETO = "contactus.aspx?item=1077&pid=0";
            NAVIGATETO2 = "contactus.aspx?item=1077&pid=0";
            PARENTMENUID = "<null>";
            PROTECTED = "<null>";
            parentmenuid2 = "<null>";
        }
    );
}
```

created from JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "MENUID": 1072.0,
      "MENUDESC": "HOME           ",
      "PARENTMENUID": null,
      "NAVIGATETO": "content.aspx?item=1072&pid=0",
      "NAVIGATETO2": "default.aspx?item=1072&pid=0",
      "PROTECTED": null,
      "parentmenuid2": null
    },
    {
      "MENUID": 1073.0,
      "MENUDESC": "PRODUCTS &amp; SERVICES",
      "PARENTMENUID": null,
      "NAVIGATETO": "#",
      "NAVIGATETO2": "default.aspx?item=1073&pid=0",
      "PROTECTED": null,
      "parentmenuid2": null
    },
    {
      "MENUID": 1074.0,
      "MENUDESC": "ABOUT US",
      "PARENTMENUID": null,
      "NAVIGATETO": "content.aspx?item=1074&pid=0",
      "NAVIGATETO2": "default.aspx?item=1074&pid=0",
      "PROTECTED": null,
      "parentmenuid2": null
    },
    {
      "MENUID": 1075.0,
      "MENUDESC": "WHAT SETS US APART",
      "PARENTMENUID": null,
      "NAVIGATETO": "content.aspx?item=1075&pid=0",
      "NAVIGATETO2": "default.aspx?item=1075&pid=0",
      "PROTECTED": null,
      "parentmenuid2": null
    },
]
}
```

I am working through sample code where they use this to extract the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *items = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But that isn't working - I get an error "invalid selector sent". I have tried all sorts of ways to access the data in the array. But all the research and answers I have found are not helping.

I need to create NSStrings from it like this:

```
NSString *text = [[menuItems objectForKey:@"Table"] objectForKey:@"MENUDESC"];
NSString *name = [[menuItems objectForKey:@"Table"] objectForKey:@"MENUID"];
```

Comment: add content of menuItem array in your question.

Comment: Why do you think `menuItems` is an array?

Comment: It's declared as an array, so I can't access it using indexForKey:

Comment: i've added the content of the menuItem array to the question.

Comment: That is not an array. Is a dictionary with a single key which is paired to an array... `Table` key is what your really want as source for your `menuItems`

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a fairly dynamic language, so even though you have `menuItems` declared as an `NSArray`, there is no guarantee as to its type at run-time. If you deserialized the JSON object from your question, and assigned it to `menuItems`, you are actually assigning to it an `NSDictionary` instance. Note that the outermost symobls of the JSON are curly-braces, representing an object (which converts to `NSDictionary`) and not square brackets, representing an array. This object has one key, `Table`, with an array as the associated value.

So what you need to do is something like this:

```
NSArray *menuItems = JSONObject[@"Table"];
```

Where `JSONObject` is what you are currently assigning to `menuItems`. After that, `menuItems` points to an array of dictionaries, each of which should be able to give you the strings you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use Following Code :

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[menuItems objectForKey:@"Table"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"MENUDESC"]);

NSLog(@"%@",[[[menuItems objectForKey:@"Table"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"MENUID"]);
```

This will return only for first Array : your can also get all value by using `for Loop:`

Answer (score 1):

That is, what is sent to you by means of the JSON string. 
It starts off with a key-value pair enclosed in {}. It only has one entry. The key of that entry is "table" and its value is an array which wraps a number of objects. The array's objects are enclosed in []. Witin the array is a number of sets of key/value pairs (encosed in {}).

So each {} will be converted into an NSDictionary, which is the appropriate container for key-value-pairs. And every [], even empty ones, will be converted into an NSArray of objects.

You can never be sure what you receive. Therefore you should always double check whether a received value ist NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString or NSNumber. (I am not sure about NSDate, to be frank.) 
Do that by using (example)

```
if ([myCurrentObject isKindOfClass[NSString class]]) {
  // process the data
} else {
  // react to the error because you were expecting a string and got something else
}
```

By doing so you give your app a chance of reacting properly, even if it cannot process the data. That is far better than aborts caused by uncaught exceptions which you currently observe.

Be prepared for receiving empty arrays and dictionarys as well. For dictionarys it is not that difficult. `objectForKey:` etc will simply return nil if the key does not exist. But `objectAtIndex:0` will throw an invalid argument exception when there isn't any object within the array. So make sure you check the length and the existance of objects received.

```
if (menuItems && [menuItems isKindOfClass[NSArray class]] && [menuItems count]) ...
```

will do. That checks first whether menuItem is not nil and then it checks whether it is an NSArray (or NSMutableArray - that will evaulate to YES too) and whether the array does contain any object at all. The latter would be achieved with a proper for loop too. 
There is no need to actually nest the if statements because it starts evaluating on the left and will stop evaluating on the first NO that is found when all conditions are connected with a logical AND `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses they were really helpful. I changed the `NSArray *menuItems;` to `NSDictionary *menuItems;` and then did this:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = [[menuItems objectForKey:@"Table"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"MENUDESC"];
NSString *name = [tweet objectForKey:@"MENUID"];
```

Which worked perfectly, gave me this result:

```
2013-03-02 03:00:44.396 App Test[616:c07] HOME             ID:1072
2013-03-02 03:00:44.396 App Test[616:c07] PRODUCTS &amp; SERVICES  ID:1073
2013-03-02 03:00:44.396 App Test[616:c07] ABOUT US  ID:1074
2013-03-02 03:00:44.397 App Test[616:c07] WHAT SETS US APART  ID:1075
2013-03-02 03:00:44.397 App Test[616:c07] CASE STUDIES  ID:1126
2013-03-02 03:00:44.397 App Test[616:c07] REQUEST PROPOSAL  ID:1076
2013-03-02 03:00:44.397 App Test[616:c07] CONTACT  ID:1077
```

Comment: Since other users helped you, particularly (judging from your comment) Hermann Klecker, it's polite to accept the answer that resolved your problem. I noticed on your other questions you commented indicating a certain user helped, or that something pointed out in an answer helped, but you haven't accepted any of the answers. So if you are not aware, I'm just letting you know of this aspect of the site. If you are aware of the role of accepting already, then please disregard this comment, I am not trying to coerce or nag, simply educate. Best of luck.